# witharrows - Problem to use a length given by \settowidth

Tags: tikz-pgf, lengths, witharrows

The following code doesn't use the offset given by `\myl`. What am I missing ?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{witharrows}

\newlength\myl

\newcommand\doublearrow[2]{
    \settowidth\myl{#1}%plus 2em
    \addtolength\myl{10pt}
    %Good length: \the\myl
    \Arrow[tikz = ->]{#1}
    \Arrow[xoffset=\myl,
           tikz = <-]{#2}
}

\begin{document}

$\begin{WithArrows}
    A  & = B \doublearrow{Explication down to.}%
                         {Explication up to.}
    \\ & = C
\end{WithArrows}$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written a new version of `witharrows` (v. 2.5 2020-06-23) in order to give the ability to define a robust command `\DoubleArrow` as required by the OP.

In this new version of `witharrows`, a new type of invidual arrow is introduced: the type `o` (for *over*). Such arrow is drawn over the other arrows as illustrated in the following example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{witharrows}

\begin{document}
$\begin{WithArrows}[groups]
A & = B     \Arrow{one}\Arrow[o,jump=3]{direct} \\
  & = C + C \Arrow{two} \\
  & = D + D + D \Arrow{three} \\
  & = E + E \\
  & = F + F 
\end{WithArrows}$
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the first code]

It's now easy to define a robust command `\DoubleArrow` with the expected behaviour:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{witharrows}
\NewDocumentCommand \DoubleArrow { O {} m m }
  {
    \Arrow[tikz=->,#1]{#2}%
    \Arrow[o,tikz=<-,#1]{#3}
  }

\begin{document}
$\begin{WithArrows}[groups]
A & = (a+b)^2 \DoubleArrow[tikz={font=\bfseries}]{expansion}{factorization} \\
  & = a^2 + 2ab+b^2 
\end{WithArrows}$
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the second code]

Comment: Great and so useful for lessons !

Answer (score 1):

For some reason you need to make the length global for this to work. (Probably `WithArrows` scans for the `\Arrow` commands and does some nice tricks with them.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{witharrows}

\newlength\myl

\newcommand\doublearrow[2]{%
    \settowidth\myl{#1}%
    \global\myl=\myl%
    \Arrow[tikz = ->]{#1}%
    \Arrow[xoffset = \dimexpr\myl+1em,tikz    = <-]{#2}%
}

\begin{document}

$\begin{WithArrows}
    A  & = B \doublearrow{Explication down to.}%
                         {Explication up to}
    \\ & = C
\end{WithArrows}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

I also added a grace distance of `1em` but this has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the trick ! I have also noticed the missing grace distance.

Comment: Yes. The command `\doublearrow` is executed in the cell of an array (an `\halign` of TeX) and each such cell is a TeX group. However, the arrows are not drawn when TeX is in that cell: they are drawn after the construction of the `\halign`: that's why a global affectation is required here.

Comment: Thanks a lot or "Merci beaucoup".

Answer (score 1):

If you want a macro `\doublearrow` which may be used several times in the same environment `{WithArrows}`, you can't use a global dimension. You have to substitute `\mylen` by its numerical value in the option `[xoffset = \mylen]` before the execution of the command `\Arrow`.

The following code gives a way to do that.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{witharrows}

\WithArrowsOptions{tikz={font=}}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \doublearrow { m m }
  {
    \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { #1 }
    \dim_set:Nn \l_tmpa_dim { \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box + 20 pt }
    \Arrow [tikz = ->] { #1 }
    \use:x { \Arrow [xoffset=\dim_use:N \l_tmpa_dim , tikz = <-] } { #2 }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}


$\begin{WithArrows} 
A & = B \doublearrow{$1+2$}{$3+4$} \\ 
  & = C \\
  & = D \doublearrow{up to down}{down to up} \\ 
  & = E
\end{WithArrows}$ 

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

In fact, this code is not perfect for two reasons.

- The argument of the first `\Arrow` is composed twice. It's a problem if there is a code with side effects in that argument (for example a `\footnote`).
- The width of the label of the first `\Arrow` is computed without applying the potential formatting options (the key `tikz={font={...}}`). If such options are used, the computed width will be wrong and the position of the second arrow will also be wrong. That's why, for an homogeneous behaviour, I have considered that `\WithArrowsOptions{tikz={font=}}` is in force.

Comment: Good ! Thanks ! Why I forget this case of use... There is stil a little problem. I have tried to use the following example but the first spacing isn't big enough : $\begin{WithArrows} A & = B \doublearrow{$1+2$}{$3+4$} \\ & = C \doublearrow{Explication down to.}{Explication up to} \\ & = D \end{WithArrows}$

Comment: You are right. I have modified my post. There is a problem with the potential formatting of the argument of the `\Arrow`. As for now, it's not possible to solve that problem without using internals of `witharrows`.

Comment: Thanks for this explanations. Maybe this could be a new feature : I always write like this when I teach to my "secondes de lycée". With my "premières de lycée" I use another syntax coming from formal methods of the computer sciences.